# Returning a reference to object from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am a complete C++ beginner so all of the concepts are quite new to me. The problem at hand is that I have a vector which consists of objects such as

```
vector<Item> inventory { item1, item2, item3 };
```

I pass it to a function by reference and then need to pass it to another function to retrieve an object which has the itemId I need

```
Item& returnItem(vector<Item> &vec, int id) {
    for(Item &i : vec) {
        if(i.getItemId() == id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

void f(vector<Item> &vec, int id) {
    Item foundItem = returnItem(vec, id);
}
```

I have another function that I would need to pass this object to but obviously it's not working as intended as using `foundItem.setItemId()` after running the `returnItem` function doesn't change anything inside the vector.

Is there any easy way to fix this or what would be a better way to do this?

Comment: `returnItem` returns a reference, but when you use `Item foundItem = returnItem(...)` you actually get a copy. To get the reference you need `Item & foundItem = returnItem(...)`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - `setItemId`, I think you need `Item& foundItem = returnItem(vec, id);`, otherwise `foundItem` is a copy of `i`;

Comment: Define "not working as intended".  A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: The `returnItem` will also need to do something if the `id` is not found in the vector.  Such as `throw returnItem_not_found();`, or returning a reference to some dummy Item that acts as a "not found" token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to know for sure what is the problem.

However - my guess is that the cause is this line:

```
Item foundItem = returnItem(vec, id);
```

`returnItem` returns a reference, but the assignment to `foundItem` actually create a copy (because `foundItem` is of type `Item`, **not** reference to `Item`).

To fix it change it to:

```
//---V---------------------------------
Item & foundItem = returnItem(vec, id);
```

Now `foundItem` will be a reference to the item in the `vector`, and modifying it will change the item in the `vector`.

Another issue you have to consider is the case where the item is not found in the `vector`. As @Eljay commented, one of the options is to throw an exception. Another is to return a reference to static  instance that represent an invalid value.